# Can't find user in a different model's method with sailsjs

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to find a way to get an User in my Team model without using many to many.

I have created a method call getCaptain in Team.js :

```
getCaptain: function(){
    User.findOne(this.admins[0],function foundUser(err, user){
    if(err) return "ERROR"
    if(!user) return "No captain"
    return user;
  }); 
},
```

In Team I have: 
"name" is the primaryKey

```
{
"name": "abc",
"id": null,
"players": [
  4
],
"admins": [
  4
],
"createdAt": "2014-11-20T18:36:10.559Z",
"updatedAt": "2014-11-20T18:36:10.559Z"
}
```

If I call `console.log(abc.getCaptain())`, it returns Undefined, even if the User 4 exists.

Is there any problem in the function itself or can't I look for an User in the Team model?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paul, i always use this syntax and it usuelly works. I tried yours as well and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried the syntax for findOne that you're using.  Have you tried the one that is in the documentation?

```
User.findOne({ id: 1 }, function(err, user) {
  // Do stuff here
});
```

Perhaps it isn't automatically recognizing the integer 4 as being a query against the id field.